# CSS select an element that contains specific classes only

Tags: css, css-selectors, styles

For example:

```
<div id="element1" class="c1 c2 c3"></div>
<div id="element2" class="c1 c2 c3 b1"></div>
```

Is there any CSS selector that will allow me to select elements that contain **only and exactly** classes c1, c2 and c3.

So I want to be able to get `element1` **but not** `element2`, and I'm not using the ID because thats actually the same on every page, but I want to be able to find when the div has only those classes and nothing else.

Thanks!

Comment: `[class="c1 c2 c3"]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```css
[class="c1 c2 c3"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="element1" class="c1 c2 c3">Item 1</div>
<div id="element2" class="c1 c2 c3 b1">Item 2</div>
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to select what I want, or anything.
The classes that I want to look for are on the body element and when matching them I want to set a contained element to display:none.

This is what the markup actually looks like:
`<body class="c1 c2 c3">
<div class="hide-this"></div>
</body>`

On some pages the classes c1, c2 and c3 and some others appear in the body tag. So I want to hide the hide-this div on any where body only has c1, c2, c3.

I tried:

`body[class="c1 c2 c3"] .hide-this{ display: none; }`<br/>
  
Am I doing that right?

Comment: Yes, you're. Here's your code working at https://jsfiddle.net/b84gg94q/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Must be some SharePoint weirdness thats preventing it from working. I see that that should be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Make sure your body has the class names in that same order and that display attribute of your targeted element is not being overridden by some other class.

Comment: I found the problem.  There were 4 spaces between c2 and c3. So the [class=""] selector needs to be exactly whats entered in the class attribute of the element. Good to know.. might be an issue.